# Deriving a new field from existing field on Jackson serialization?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a field 'state' in a class 'Location'.

```
public class Location {
   private String state = "TX";

   // getters / setters
}
```

On Jackson serialization to JSON, I would like to add a field with the same value as the 'state' field, so that backward compatibility is preserved with outdated clients which expect a 'st8' field. The JSON would look like this:

```
{
  "state": "TX",
  "st8": "TX"
}
```

I've looked into the @JsonAppend annotation, but it seems that some strange manipulation is required for this to work, which I'm uncomfortable adding to the code:

```
Location bean = new Location("TX")
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerFor(Location.class).withAttribute("st8", "TX");
String jsonString = writer.writeValueAsString(bean);
```

If I'm forced to take this approach, how would I use this within the API, as it deals purely with POJO's / DTOs and serialization is all handled magically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create extra getter for this field and `Jackson` automatically will serialise it:

```
class Location {
    private String state = "TX";

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    /**
     * backward compatibility
     */
    public String getSt8() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```